# session_id, cookie, session management

Tags: session

should I explictly send session_id as an http parameter in my ajax calls since 
some browser might disable cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the possibility of an average non-techy user disabling cookies.

Well if sending the session_id() makes you feel better than go ahead.

Comment: yes change is low that the cookie is disabled.  but sending session_id in every request would be extra work, do people usually not do it then?

Comment: developers usually don't bother doing it.